# Curly brace with arrows pointing to specific code

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I would like to use horizontal brackets within a code environment like in the following example: [image]

That's as far as what I have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[yshift=2pt](#1){};}

% Command to place a TikZ anchor at the current position
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \coordinate (#1) at (0,0) {};}

\newcommand{\highlighty}[2]{%
  \draw[yellow,line width=14pt,opacity=0.4]%
    ([yshift=4pt]#1) -- ([yshift=4pt]#2);%
}

\newcommand{\highlightg}[2]{%
  \draw[green,line width=14pt,opacity=0.4]%
    ([yshift=4pt]#1) -- ([yshift=4pt]#2);%
}


\usepackage{xcolor}


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    escapeinside={*}{*},
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,title=\small \textbf{Programm:}~\texttt{L1\_2\_2\_Funktion\_mit\_Parameter}, escapechar=*]
def nutzer_gruessen(*\mytikzmark{hl1Start}*p_vorname*\tikzmark{A}*, p_nachname*\mytikzmark{hl1End}*):
   print("Herzlich willkommen,", p_vorname, p_nachname)

vorname = input("Bitte Vorname eingeben: ")
nachname = input("Bitte Nachname eingeben: ")
nutzer_gruessen(*\mytikzmark{hl2Start}*vorname*\tikzmark{B}*, nachname*\mytikzmark{hl2End}*)
\end{lstlisting}
\tikzset{Empharrow/.style={dashed,red,thick,->,arrows={-Triangle[width=3pt]}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\highlighty{hl1Start}{hl1End}
\highlightg{hl2Start}{hl2End}
%\draw[Empharrow](B)-- ++(0, -3cm)|-(A);
%\draw[Empharrow](B)--+(5.5cm,0)|-(A.south east);
%\draw [Empharrow] (B) |-([shift={(8cm,-3mm)}]B.south east)-- ([shift={(6.5cm,3mm)}]A.north east)-|(A);
\draw [Empharrow] (B) |-([shift={(7cm,-2mm)}]B.south east)-- ([shift={(5.8cm,3mm)}]A.north east)-|(A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How do I manage to insert the horizontal brackets within a listing environment?

I would also like to know how I can manage the highlighting in such a way that I don't have to create a new command for each new color.

Comment: `\newcommand{\highlight}[3][]{\draw[line width=14pt,opacity=0.4,#1] ([yshift=4pt]#2) -- ([yshift=4pt]#3);}` and you can use it as `\highlight[yellow]{hl1Start}{hl1End}`.

Comment: The tikzmark library (which supercedes the commands you're using) has a library of its own that interacts with listings that might be of some use.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you very much! I've read it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's reorganize.

In your code you use `\tmS` (start)  and `\tmT` (target) to mark and highlight the given area. The values `st` and `tt` are used to change the size of the rectangle. The optional argment to `\tmS` is applied to the `\fill` which you can use to change the color (or any drawing actually) as well as the values `st` and `tt` for this individual highlight.

All four corners of this rectangle are marked by four coordinates (it might be better to use one single node here but this is easier) which will later be used by `oBrace` and `uBrace` which in turn use the style `bracy`.
These add further coordinate just at the tip of the brace which are  then finally used with the `Empharrow` key which also installs a custom `to path`.
Though, this is hard coded to come from an UnderBrace and go to an OverBrace.

I'm using the `aboveskip` and `abovecaptionskip` values so that the listing environment leaves more room for your arrow.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz} % loads xcolor
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
  st/.initial={-.1em,-.3em}, tt/.initial={.1em,.8em},
  /pgf/decoration/raise/.append code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgf/decoration/raise}{#1},
  bracy/.style={decorate, thick, decoration={name=brace, raise=-.1em}},
  uBrace/.style={
    bracy,
    insert path={
      (#1-br) -- coordinate[midway, yshift=
        -\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/raise}] (#1-b)
      (#1-bl)}},
  oBrace/.style={
    bracy,
    insert path={
      (#1-tl) -- coordinate[midway, yshift=
        \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/raise}] (#1-t)
      (#1-tr)}},
  Empharrow/.style={
    dashed, red, thick, arrows={-Triangle[width=3pt, length=4pt]},
    shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,
    to path={-- ++(down:.7em) -- ++ (right:#1) |- ([yshift=.7em]\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget)}
  },
}
\newcommand*\tmS[2][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=0pt]
  \fill[#1](\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/st}) coordinate (#2-bl)
    rectangle ([shift={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tt})}]pic cs:mytm-#2)
    coordinate (#2-tr) coordinate (#2-tl) at (#2-tr-|#2-bl)
    coordinate (#2-br) at (#2-tr|-#2-bl);%
}
\newcommand*\tmT[1]{\tikzmark{mytm-#1}}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  escapeinside={*}{*},
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
  commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  keepspaces=true,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
\noindent Foo \hrulefill Bar
\begin{lstlisting}[
  language=Python,
  title=\small\textbf{Programm:}~\texttt{L1\_2\_2\_Funktion\_mit\_Parameter},
  aboveskip=\dimexpr.5em+\medskipamount,         % extra space for brace and line
  abovecaptionskip=\dimexpr.5em+\smallskipamount,% extra space for brace and line
]
def nutzer_gruessen(*\tmS[yellow]{hl1}*p_vorname, p_nachname*\tmT{hl1}*):
   print("Herzlich willkommen,", p_vorname, p_nachname)

vorname = input("Bitte Vorname eingeben: ")
nachname = input("Bitte Nachname eingeben: ")
nutzer_gruessen(*\tmS[green]{hl2}*vorname, nachname*\tmT{hl2}*)
\end{lstlisting}
\noindent Foo \hrulefill Bar
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[yellow!50!black, oBrace=hl1];
\draw[green!50!black, uBrace=hl2];
\draw[Empharrow=6cm] (hl2-b) to (hl1-t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You managed to do everything very nicely, congrats. Especially the highlights which I was struggling with.